# current datetime is 6 hours behind nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I need to compare the current datetime with datetime in database column. In my computer `new Date()` returns datetime that is `2023-05-21T04:35:07.903Z` whereas My computer time is `10:35:07`. How can I adjust this?

**Note : I cannot convert them to string as I need to compare them.**
**My code :**

```
        console.log("current time", new Date());
        console.log("db time", new Date(results[i].start));

        if ( new Date(results[i].start) >= new Date()){
            ..............
        }
```

Comment: use `new Date().toUTCString()`

Comment: What's wrong with the comparisons you do now? In what format is `results[i].start`?

Comment: results[i].start is in UTC format. For example, 2023-05-21T04:35:07.903Z. I am setting this acccording to my local time. But my current local time is 6 hours before. Thats why I am unable to compare results[i].start with my current time as current time is 6 hours before.

Comment: UTC is not a format, it's a timezone. If you're saving local time in UTC then *that's* the real problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to be confused with JavaScript [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

> A JavaScript date is fundamentally specified as the time in milliseconds that has elapsed since the epoch, which is defined as the midnight at the beginning of January 1, 1970, UTC (equivalent to the UNIX epoch). This timestamp is *timezone-agnostic* and uniquely defines an instant in history.

If your JavaScript engine (browser or Node.js) is in a +0600 timezone (a.k.a. UTC/GMT+6, e.g. in Kazakhstan), when you do `new Date`, you get an *instant* that is *independant from timezone*, but when expressed it must be displayed according to a timezone, so it can be displayed indifferently as:

- 04:35 am UTC
- 10:35 am UTC+6

The `Z` suffix at the end of the date string indeed indicates that the time is expressed in UTC timezone. Therefore "2023-05-21T04:35:07.903**Z**" means 4:35 am in UTC, e.g. in London. And 10:35 am in Kazakhstan.

---

If `results[i].start` value is `"2023-05-21T04:35:07.903Z"` and means 04:35 am in UTC (e.g. London) / 10:35 am in Kazakhstan, as it should, then you do not need to adjust `new Date`: when you do `new Date` at 10:00 am in Kazakhstan, you get 04:00Z, hence *before* `results[i].start`.

```js
new Date("2023-05-21T04:35:07.903Z") >= new Date() // true if executed on 2023-05-21 at 10 am in UTC+6
```

If, on the contrary, and for whatever reason, the value `"2023-05-21T04:35:07.903Z"` in your database should be interpreted as *4:35 am in Kazakhstan*, then indeed you need either to:

- change the offset of `new Date` so that your local time is also shifted as if it were in UTC (instead of UTC+6)
- shift the offset of the database value so that it now really means time in UTC+6

You could easily achieve the latter by omitting the `Z` suffix, so that the datetime string is no longer interpreted as expressed in UTC (hence it will be interpreted as expressed in local time instead):

```js
function dateConvertedToLocal(datetime) {
  const withoutZsuffix = datetime.replace(/Z$/i, "");
  return new Date(withoutZsuffix);
}

dateConvertedToLocal("2023-05-21T04:35:07.903Z") >= new Date // false if executed on 2023-05-21 at 10 am in UTC+6
```